# \[js\] 'property declartions' can only be used in a ts file

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
updateDimensions = () => {
```

The above causes the [js] 'property declarations' can only be used in a [ts] file.

I pushed this as a bug to VSCode and it was closed as fixed in TypeScript, so anyone know how to get the thing to work in VSCode? There are other things that cause similar issues.

```
static propTypes = {
```

Doing fat arrow functions is nice in React since I don't have to do bind(this) all over the place, and of course you need 'static propTypes' to define the properties.

Answer (score 9):

I have disabled this by overriding

```
    "javascript.validate.enable": false
```

Using the main menu, you can open and define user settings by selecting File → Preferences → Settings (Visual Studio Code 1.9.1)

Install VS extensions for ES6 and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

1. Install the TS 2.0 beta (npm i -g typescript@beta)
2. Open up user settings. (file-preferences-user settings) add something similar to

   "typescript.tsdk": "/home/jeff.lindholm/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.0/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"

This worked for me.

Comment: maybe it worked for you. But could you explain how?  I'm looking at a .js file and not a .ts file and getting this error. By installing typescript my problem in JS will be solved?  Why?!

Comment: and what is /home/myuser/.nvm   I don't see any .nvm in my (windows 10) user directory.